# django-taggit field not saving list Initially

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I am using django-taggit for tags. I want to add all other fields of the same table in tags automatically when I save the data table. I am using the postsave method but all fields value are saved in the tags table but not in the Tags field of resource table.

```
class resource(models.Model):
  title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
  size=models.CharField( max_length=20, default="")
  desc=models.TextField(default="")
  file=models.FileField(default="", blank=True)
  url= models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
  Brand = models.ForeignKey(brand,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
  Model = models.ForeignKey(model,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
  Categories = models.ForeignKey(category,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
  update_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
  slug=models.SlugField(default="")
  Tags = TaggableManager()

def tag_set(sender, instance,*arg, **kwargs):
  ans= array_tag(instance)
   # print(and)
  mylist = ["firmware", "download", "gsm"]
  instance.title='check'
  instance.Tags.add(*ans)
post_save.connect(tag_set, sender=resource)  
def array_tag(instance):
  return [instance.title ,instance.desc,instance.size, instance.Brand.title ,instance.Model.title ,instance.Categories.title]
```